# why am I getting null when trying to get a link token from plaid?

Tags: ios, google-cloud-functions, plaid

I'm working in an iOS app with a Plaid integration to verify assets.

I cannot make the damn link token creation work...I get a 200 response but only NULL for the token

[image]

does anybody know what might be happening?
[image]

this is the cloud function

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
//import { Configuration, PlaidApi, PlaidEnvironments } from "plaid";
const { Configuration, PlaidApi, PlaidEnvironments } = require("plaid");

exports.createPlaidLinkToken = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const customerId = context.auth.uid;

  //new instance version
  const configuration = new Configuration({
    basePath: PlaidEnvironments.development,
    baseOptions: {
      headers: {
        "PLAID-CLIENT-ID": functions.config().plaid.client_id,
        "PLAID-SECRET": functions.config().plaid.secret,
      },
    },
  });

  const plaidClient = new PlaidApi(configuration);

  //call the createLinkToken  METHOD of tge plaidClient instance!
  return plaidClient
    .linkTokenCreate({
      user: {
        client_user_id: customerId,
      },
      client_name: "Reny",
      products: ["auth"],
      country_codes: ["US"],
      language: "en",
    })
    .then((apiResponse) => {
      const linkToken = apiResponse.link_token;
      return linkToken;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        "internal",
        " Unable to create plaid link token: " + err
      );
    });
});
```

cloud functions logs
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the body of the response to the /link/token/create request?

Comment: I just retested with postman and it works. I use the https://development.plaid.com/link/token/create
{
  "expiration": "2022-01-03T01:55:42Z",
  "link_token": "link-development-31f73392-4a4b-4539-9740-ccb458fa1eb4",
  "request_id": "kVTAQprXkdNNYAi"
}

Comment: but it doesn't work with the npm plaid code I'm using
https://www.npmjs.com/package/plaid

Comment: I wonder if I should ditch the firebase cloud function all together and host my function somewhere else

Comment: What happens if you console log the apiResponse directly in the cloud function? I suspect the issue is your function is returning `apiResponse.link_token` instead of something like `apiResponse.data.link_token`

Comment: bingo!, @ToddKerpelman I used apiResponse.data.link_token and it worked!, a trillion thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to provide closure for anybody who was curious, this issue was fixed by changing the lines...

```
.then((apiResponse) => {
  const linkToken = apiResponse.link_token;
  return linkToken;
})
```

to...

```
.then((apiResponse) => {
  const linkToken = apiResponse.data.link_token;
  return linkToken;
})
```